# Including unmanaged jars on classpath, when building scala project using sbt

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to build an old project.

The project depends on a java package found in `sparrow-1.0.jar`

I copied the jar to the `lib_managed/jars` and `lib` directory, however when compiling I still get a missing class path error.

`project/SparkBuild.sbt` contains a referenec to `lib` directory

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <<= baseDirectory map { base => (base / "lib" ** "*.jar").classpath },
```

and the contents of `./lib`

```
root@26eefef538b1:/sparrow/spark-sparrow# tree -D lib
lib
|-- jars
|   `-- sparrow-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
|-- sparrow-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
`-- sparrow.jar
```

However when I compile I still get the same errors:

```
root@26eefef538b1:/sparrow/spark-sparrow# sbt/sbt package assembly
[info] Loading project definition from /sparrow/spark-sparrow/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /sparrow/spark-sparrow/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/sparrow/spark-sparrow/)
[info] Compiling 260 Scala sources and 16 Java sources to /sparrow/spark-sparrow/core/target/scala-2.9.3/classes...
[error] /sparrow/spark-sparrow/core/src/main/scala/spark/scheduler/sparrow/SparrowScheduler.scala:28: not found: object edu
[error] import edu.berkeley.sparrow.thrift.FrontendService
[error]        ^
```

Is there a command line option or additional configuration I am missing for importing add classpath from the jars to the project?

The project is compiled against `scala 2.9.3` using `sbt 0.12.3`

I noticed I can run scala with the jar  on the classpath and import the objects.

```
root@26eefef538b1:/sparrow/spark-sparrow# scala -cp $SPARROW_JAR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_201).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import edu.berkeley.sparrow.thrift.FrontendService
import edu.berkeley.sparrow.thrift.FrontendService

scala>
```

Comment: The directory for _unmanaged_ libraries is `lib`, try using that or changing the folder in **SBT**. See [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies) for more information.

Comment: Thanks I have tried placing the jar in the same directory as root of the project too. Neither worked.

Comment: what version of sbt are you using ? 
 Have you tried commenting out the `unmanagedJars` line ? if the jars are in `lib`, you don't need to specify it.

Comment: I get the same error when commenting the `unmanagedJars` line.  `scala 2.9.2` and `sbt 0.12.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the lib directory and jar to a sub directory.
e.g. `./core/lib/sparrow.jar` seems to have solved the problem